# Successful Callbacks, but <script src = “//website.com/?variables” > still not loading in div after ajax

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, jquery

I can't get the following script file and its contents to load into a div.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//bcg.coupons.com/?scriptId=47051&bid=1293740001&format=718x940&bannerType=3"></script>
```

I created a js fiddle to show my attempts:

http://jsfiddle.net/BF8K2/6/

I get successful callbacks, but the script contents still don't show in the divs. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This script uses `document.write()` .

Because of that it can't be used after the document has finished loading(what it is the case in all your attempts...except `$.load()`, what  fails because of the different domains , and it also wouldn't do anything on the same domain because the script is not embedded in script-tags and will be handled as text )

Your "successfull callbacks" are neither callbacks nor successfull, they are text that you append in any case.